# Table without header, columns same size as table before

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I'd like to create a table with content from my database. I have a table without a header for multiple reasons (e.q. scrolling). Is it possible set the colums to the same width as the table before without JS? I dont want to add a class to each td element if possible. Not all columns have the same width. Nth-child is a bad solution because I have multiple tables.. :/

Here is a shorter version of my table:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.h1 {
  width: 125px;
}

.h2 {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="h1">
      <span>a</span>
    </th>
    <th class="h2">
      <span>b</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>c</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>d</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If only reason is scrolling you can do it with one table

Comment: Use colgroup for this. Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup

Comment: colgroup is for use within a table, the question relates to matching columns for multiple tables

Comment: @pc_coder the problem with one table I had is that I don't know the height of tbody because the table stretches to the bottom. Or is there another way without setting height? I used flex: 1 to stretch.

Comment: If you just want to match the height it is very simple with js?

Answer (score 0):

one of the tables has header and one of them doesn't. and in your css you do not specify the table without header... you should has a code like this 
`table , tr, td{}`